# move_uploaded_file not working as it should

Tags: php

I've searched around but I can't find my issue. I have a simple script that uploads a file to the target-folder.

```
$target = "img/fotos-artikels/";
$target .= basename($_FILES["uploadBron"]["name"]); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadBron"]["tmpname"], $target)) {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["uploadBron"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo " Sorry there was a problem";
}
```

And this is the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <label for="txtBronNaam">Naam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtBronNaam" id="txtBronNaam" value="" /><br />
    <label for="uploadBron">File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadBron" id="uploadBron" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Voeg bron toe" />
</form>
```

Do I have to enable something in apache maybe?

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'its not working' ? Does the file not move? Does the funtion return a true or false? It could be as issue of write permissions in your target directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tmpname` should be `tmp_name`